# How many functions $ f: \{1, 2, 3, \dots, 10\} \to \{0,1\}$ satisfy $f(1) + f(2) + \dots + f(10) = 2$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, functions

How many functions $ f: \{1, 2, 3, \dots, 10\} \to \{0,1\}$ have this property: $$f(1) + f(2) + \dots + f(10) = 2.$$

I understand just $2$ functions can be $1$, the rest have to be $0$, in total there are $2^{10}$ functions, but how can I find out how many of them have this property?

Comment: What is the range again? It cannot be $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out its {0, 1}

Comment: For two numbers in $\{1,\dots,10\}$, we must have that $f$ takes the value $1$, and it is $0$ elsewhere, so you are counting...

Comment: i understood, its combinations of 10 taken 2 at a time = 45

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: As you said in the question, exactly two of the functions values must be $1$, and the other eight must be $0$. How many ways are there to choose $2$ things from a set of $10$ things (i.e., to choose which two function values are to be $1$)?

Answer (score 2):

$$ $$ [$$ 10 \choose 2$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) $$ $$ $ $

Comment: (Click it.) $ $

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to be the case, two elements in the domain must map to 1, and the rest map to 0:

$\binom{10}{2}$

Comment: But $2$ isn't in the codomain.

Comment: Except that $2$ is not in the range of $f$.

Comment: @RossMilikan Right...I didn't see the edit